# FullCalendar.io - load different events on click

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-3

I'm using https://fullcalendar.io/ and the data loads fine initially. The code is inherited from a previous developer (below)

My question is how would I load a different set of events when someone clicked a button? Let's say I had several different type of events and a button for each and each button would load a different set of events. How would I go about doing this?

I have tried the following but this doesn't seem to refresh the events (delete old, add new)

```
  $('.status').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var status = $(this).data('status'); 
    $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     dataType: "json",
     url: "/Office_calender/loadEventstatus",
     data: {
      status:status
     },
     success: function(result){
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents', function () { return true; });
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('removeEventSources');
       $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', result, true);
       
     }
   });
  });
```

Thank you

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
defaultDate: new Date(),
schedulerLicenseKey: 'XXXXX',
defaultView: 'month',
editable: false,
selectable: true,
selectHelper: true,
allDaySlot: false,
disableDragging: true,
slotEventOverlap: true,
selectOverlap: false,
contentHeight: 400,
eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
minTime: "06:00:00",
maxTime: "23:00:00",
dayOfMonthFormat: 'ddd DD',
firstDay: 1,
scrollTime: "08:00:00",
header: {
    left: 'prev,next month',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'prev,next month'
},
views: {
    agendaTwoDay: {
        type: 'agenda',
        duration: {
            days: 2
        },
        groupByResource: true
    }
},
events: [ <
    ? php
    if ($allevents != 0) {
        foreach($allevents as $val) {
            ? > {
                id: '<?php echo $val->ecd_id;?>',
                title: '<?php echo $val->ecd_name;?>',
                start: '<?php echo $val->ecd_date_from;?>',
                end: '<?php echo $val->ecd_date_to;?>',
                backgroundColor: '#3a87ad',
            }, <
            ? php
        }
    } ? >
],
eventClick: function(eventObj) {
    if (eventObj.id) {
        var status = eventObj.id;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "<?php echo site_url(); ?>superadmin_dashboard/event_D",
            data: {
                status: status
            },
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(result) {
                var date = result.ecd_date_from;
                var dateAr = date.split('-');
                var firstday = dateAr[2] + '-' + dateAr[1] + '-' + dateAr[0];

                var ldate = result.ecd_date_to;
                var ldateAr = ldate.split('-');
                var lastday = ldateAr[2] + '-' + ldateAr[1] + '-' + ldateAr[0];
                $('#myModal').modal('show');
                $('#event_name').html(result.ecd_name);
                $('.requirementsmodal').attr('data-event_id', result.ecd_id);
                $('#myModalLabel').html(result.ecd_name);
                $('#event_description').html(result.ecd_desc);
                $('#event_firstday').html(result.ecd_date_from);
                $('#event_lastday').html(result.ecd_date_to);
                $('#event_type').html(result.category_name);
                $('#event_address').html(result.ecd_location);
                $('#client_name').html(result.client_name);
                $('.stafflist').data('eventId', result.ecd_id);
                $('.eventName').html(result.ecd_name);
                $('.clientName').html(result.client_name);
                //$('.eventdates').html(firstday+" - "+lastday);
                $('#event_dates').html(firstday + " - " + lastday);
                $('.eventAddress').html(result.ecd_location);
                $('.edit_events').attr('href', '<?php echo base_url(); ?>editEventDetails/' + result.ecd_id + '/1');
            }
        });
        return false; // prevents browser from following link in current tab.
    } else {
        alert('Clicked ' + eventObj.title);
    }
}
});
});
```

Comment: Where would the new events come from? If you make it so that you can fetch events via an Ajax request to the server, and pass a parameter indicating which set of events is to be retrieved, you can do this fairly easily. See also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/events-json-feed so you can see how to point fullCalendar at the URL for fetching events . There's a section in there about sending custom parameters dynamically. See also https://fullcalendar.io/docs/v3/refetchEvents - when your user selects to view different events, you'd call this to trigger the new request from fullCalendar

Comment: I've added the code I'm currently using to try and refresh the events

Comment: That's less efficient, but it could be made to work if you weren't immediately removing the event source straight after you've added it! My approach is better though because you can also filter the events by date, instead of refreshing events for all dates every time - when in reality someone is only looking at a few days or weeks at a time